# Add a new identifier in id column of long format by group

Tags: r, tidyverse

Suppose I want to create a new `class` identifier called `outdoors` in the `mpg` dataset that calculates the sum of `hwy` mileage for jeeps, land rovers, and subarus between groups 1 and 2. Is there a way to do it in **tidyverse** *without* converting it to wide format? Here's some code (that doesn't work, of course) that shows what I'm trying to achieve.

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mpg)

mpg_new <- mpg %>%
   mutate(group = rep(c(1,2), times = 117)) %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(hwy[class="outdoors"] = sum(hwy[manufacturer=="jeep"], hwy[manufacturer=="land rover"], hwy[manufacturer=="subaru"]))

# class="outdoors" is the new identifier I am trying to create within the class variable
```

Comment: I don't understand the goal. I would suggest trying to demonstrate the problem on a dataset small enough that you can show the desired output.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to do 2 or 3 things at once. (a) you want to change the values of some rows of the `class` column to `"outdoors"`? Which rows do you want to update - is it all rows where `manufacturer %in% c("jeep", "land rover", "subaru")`? To me, that seems like step 1. Then, (b) for these "outdoors" rows, you want to compute the sum of the `hwy` column by this arbitrary `group` column, and you want to replace the current `hwy` values with this computed sum. Is that right?

Comment: If I am correct, generally the `tidyverse` way to update some but not all rows is to use `ifelse` or `case_when`. So, to update those manufacturers to set the class to "outdoors", you would do `mutate(class = ifelse(manufacturer %in% c("jeep", "land rover", "subaru"), "outdoors", class))`. And  in a subsequent `mutate` you could use a similar approach to update the `hwy` values, `mutate(hwy = ifelse(class == "outdoor", sum(hwy), hwy), .by = c(group, class))`

Comment: Beautiful, it works (and better yet it works with the real data I've working with)! Thank you so much for your help. If you want to put it as an answer I'll mark it accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the tidyverse way to update some but not all rows is to use `ifelse` or `case_when`, with the original value as the "else" or default.

We'll proceed in two steps, first update the `class` column, then update the `hwy` column:

```
mpg_new = mpg |>
   mutate(
     group = rep(c(1,2), times = 117),
     class = ifelse(manufacturer %in% c("jeep", "land rover", "subaru"), "outdoors", class)
   ) %>%
   group_by(group, class) %>%
   mutate(
     hwy = ifelse(class == "outdoor", sum(hwy), hwy)
    )
```

I'd also note that this could have been easily demonstrated on a 6-row data frame with a lot more clarity - I'd strongly suggest trying to find **minimal** examples - it's easier to understand and easier to debug.